# What is the fastest SUV in GTA online?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

Which one is the fastest SUV in GTA online till Cayo Perico Heist update (release date December 15th, 2020)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Broughy](https://broughy.com/gta5carsoverview), who tests vehicle top speed, and lap times by driving them on a track (which takes in the vehicle stats: speed, acceleration, handling, weight, among other stats, into consideration), the current fastest SUV is the [**Pegassi Toros**](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Toros), with the [Lampadati Novak](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Novak) second, and the [Übermacht Rebla GTS](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Rebla_GTS) third.

The fastest SUV by the top speed (game files) stat alone is the [**Übermacht Rebla GTS**](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Rebla_GTS), with the [Pegassi Toros](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Toros) second, and the [Lampadati Novak](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Novak) third.

Putting the stats of those three SUVs here for better comparison:

|  | Pegassi Toros | Lampadati Novak | Übermacht Rebla GTS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Top Speed - Real (Broughy) | 127.50 mph (205.19 km/h) | 126.00 mph (202.78 km/h) | 123.50 mph (198.75 km/h) |
| Lap Time (Broughy) (m:ss.000) | 1:04.865 | 1:06.500 | 1:06.700 |
| Top Speed (Game Files) | 96.31 mph (155.00 km/h) | 95.07 mph (153.00 km/h) | 97.87 mph (157.50 km/h) |
| Price | $498,000 | $608,000 | $1,175,000 |
| Mass/Weight | 2,200 KG | 2,100 KG | 2,185 KG |
| Release Date | 2018-12-18 | 2019-11-07 | 2019-12-12 |
| Title Update | 1.46 Arena War | 1.48 Diamond Casino & Resort | 1.49 Diamond Casino Heist |

Sources:

- [Broughy - GTA 5 Vehicle Info, Performance & Tier Lists](https://broughy.com/gta5carsoverview)
- [Broughy's top speed testing methodology](https://broughy.com/topspeeddesc)
- [Broughy's lap time testing methodology](https://broughy.com/laptimedesc)
- [GTABase.com GTA V Vehicle Database](https://www.gtabase.com/grand-theft-auto-v/vehicles/#sort=attr.ct132.frontend_value&sortdir=desc&attr.ct1.value=suvs&page=1)

Answer (score 3):

According to this [article](https://www.sportskeeda.com/esports/gta-online-5-fastest-suvs-game), which was written around three months before the Cayo Perico update:

> **1) Pegassi Toros**
>
> Price: $498,000
>
> Top Speed: 127.50 mph (205.19 km/h)
>
> The Pegassi Toros might be one of the most visually impressive SUVs on
> this list. It takes inspiration from real-life vehicles such as
> Lamborghini Urus, Lamborghini Aventador, and Audi Q8.
>
> In addition to being one of the nicer looking vehicles in GTA Online,
> the Toros also packs decent performance that makes it an extremely
> appealing buy in the game.

So, it appears that that was the best and the fastest SUV in the game at that time.